# Effect of competition on the slope of NKPC, Calvo vs. Rotemberg

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, new-keynesian-economics

I was just going through some notes on NK models, and I noticed the following.

Under **Calvo** price setting, the slope of the NKPC is

$$
\kappa_C = \frac{1 - \alpha}{1 - \alpha + \alpha \epsilon} \frac{(1 - \beta \theta)(1 - \theta)}{\theta}\left(\sigma + \frac{\varphi + \alpha}{1 - \alpha}\right),
$$
where $\alpha$ is the returns to scale in the production function $Y_t = A_t N_t^{1 - \alpha}$, $\epsilon$ is the elasticity of substitution between the differentiated goods the firms provide, $\beta$ is the discount rate, $\varphi$ is the inverse elasticity of labour supply, $\sigma$ is the intertemporal elasticity of substitution, and $\theta$ is the degree of price stickiness (one minus the arrival rate of price change opportunities for firms). Here more price stickiness and a **higher degree of substitutability lead to a lower slope of the NKPC.** If $\alpha = 0$, there is **no effect of a higher degree of substitutability on the NKPC slope**.

Under **Rotemberg** adjustment costs, the slope of the NKPC is (assuming already $\alpha = 0$)

$$
\kappa_R = \frac{\epsilon - 1}{\phi}(\sigma + \varphi).
$$

So here, **a higher $\epsilon$ corresponds to a steeper NKPC slope**.

I often hear that these two parametrizations are equivalent up to first order. For dynamics, I imagine they are indeed equivalent. But as to the effect of more competition (higher $\epsilon$), they seem to be at odds. Am I missing something? Why the difference? Is there an intuitive explanation for it?